# Convert DB2 MAX(DECODE to HIVE

Tags: hive, db2

I have a code that was written for DB2 and now need to rewrite it for hive and I am unable to find equivalent code for MAX(DECODE in HIVE

My Current CODE

```
 SELECT
            E.CHARGE_ARRANGEMENT_NUMBER ,
            E.MIG_MAIN_PROD_CODE ,
            MAX(DECODE(UPPER(E.MIG_EXTRA_ACTION), 'KEEP', E.MIG_EXTRA_ACTION)) AS EXTRAS_KEEP ,
            MAX(DECODE(UPPER(E.MIG_EXTRA_ACTION), 'DROP', E.EXTRAS_LIST)) AS EXTRAS_DROP
        FROM
            EXTRA_MAPPINGS_PRE E
        GROUP BY
            E.CHARGE_ARRANGEMENT_NUMBER ,
            E.MIG_MAIN_PROD_CODE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you need to use `if` or `case when then end`.

```
 SELECT
            E.CHARGE_ARRANGEMENT_NUMBER ,
            E.MIG_MAIN_PROD_CODE ,
            MAX(IF(UPPER(E.MIG_EXTRA_ACTION) ='KEEP', E.MIG_EXTRA_ACTION,null) ) AS EXTRAS_KEEP ,
            MAX(IF(UPPER(E.MIG_EXTRA_ACTION) ='DROP', E.EXTRAS_LIST,null)) AS EXTRAS_DROP
        FROM
            EXTRA_MAPPINGS_PRE E
        GROUP BY
            E.CHARGE_ARRANGEMENT_NUMBER ,
            E.MIG_MAIN_PROD_CODE
```

You can use `case-when` if you are not comfortable with if.